# Django html form data throws NoReverseMatch

Tags: python, html, django, forms, django-forms

I have a simple Django site and im trying to build a form which is hidden until i click Add daata.
Once i Click Add data it show show me below input aread like First Name, Last Name and Country. Once Submited it should redirect me to new page which will list all the names present in DB.

Below is my Html form code :

```
<div id="sub_div2">
    <a href="/myapp/mylink">
        <h4> Add  Data</h4>
    </a>
    <p>
        <button onclick="myFunction()">Add New Data</button>
    </p>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Add New data</button>
    </p>
    <form id="myDIV" style="display" action="{% url 'data_app:forminput' %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div style="margin:0;padding:0">

            <label for="fname">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name..">
            <br>
            <br>
            <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name..">
            <br>
            <br>
            <label for="country">Country</label>
            <select id="country" name="country">
                <option value="australia">Australia</option>
                <option value="canada">Canada</option>
                <option value="usa">USA</option>
            </select>
            <br>
            <br>

            <input type="submit" value="Submit">

    </form>
    <br>
    </div>
    <br>
```

And my Project url.py is as below urls

```
url(r'^', include('data_app.urls', namespace='data_app')),
url(r'^index$', views.index, name='index'),
url(r'^forminput$', views.data_update, name='data_update'),
```

and my views.py as below function

```
def data_update(request):
    if request.POST:
        messages.success(request, 'Form submission successful')
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

When i try this i get below error :
Reverse for 'forminput' not found. 'forminput' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

I want to enter form data and parse that how do i do it ? can someone pls help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't got a URL pattern named "forminput". The URL with the path "forminput" has the *name* "data_update' so that's what you should use in your url tag:

```
<form action="{% url 'data_app:data_update' %}"
```

Note, you're not submitting a file so you don't need the `enctype` attribute.

Comment: Thank you that worked. Oh yes, initially my idea was to add file.

Comment: now i want to direct to another page basically a form page with inout fields when i click on Add Data.. how do i do it ?